# My bar plot doesn't line up with the xbar and doesn't get the right colors (Plotly/Python)

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I want to build the bar plot using plotly express (px.bar), but when I define the color, the bar plot doesn't line up with the x bar, just something like this

**before defining color**

[image]

**after defining color**

[image: bar plot modified]

the bar doesn't line up with the xbar after I define the color parameter, not like default bar plot, and why the color doesn't match up with the color column in my dataframe?

here's the code and dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Grape'],
    'Count': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3],
    'Color': ['crimson', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'crimson', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey']
})

import plotly.express as px
fig_bar = px.bar(df, x='label', y='Count', color = 'Color',
                 barmode='group')

fig_bar.show()
```

**Dataframe**

```
    label   Count   Color
0   Apple   1   crimson
1   Banana  2   lightslategrey
2   Orange  2   lightslategrey
3   Grape   2   lightslategrey
4   Apple   3   crimson
5   Banana  5   lightslategrey
6   Orange  6   lightslategrey
7   Grape   3   lightslategrey
8   Grape   3   lightslategrey
```

anyone here knows why that happen? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that different `label` values in your dataframe share the same `Color`? How do you expect to display this? If you do not plan to force a specific color sequence, a simple option is to use `fig_bar = px.bar(df, x='label', y='Count', color = 'label')`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to build the plot that highlight the apple one, so it would be like this [link](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#customizing-individual-bar-colors) but I want to do that in px @Sheldon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `barmode="group"`
After removing barmode, the plot performs as intended.

Also to get the colours from the dataframe to display for each bar, you will need to specify the `color_discrete_sequence`. See [this](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html) for more detail.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Grape'],
    'Count': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3],
    'Color': ['crimson', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'crimson', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey', 'lightslategrey']
})

chart_df = df.groupby(by = ['label', 'Color']).sum().reset_index()
fig_bar = px.bar(chart_df, x='label', y='Count', color = 'Color', color_discrete_sequence=chart_df['Color'])
fig_bar.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig_bar.show()
```

[image: plot2]

##### Note:

If you wanted to keep the **white lines within the bars**, then you would use this instead:

```
fig_bar = px.bar(df, x='label', y='Count', color = 'Color', color_discrete_sequence=df['Color'])
```